# Function replication IBM

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, ibm-cloud, replication

I have an issue related to an action within the 'function' that I want to implement. The goal is for my action to first determine if there are objects with a specific tag in my COS (Cloud Object Storage) Bucket 1. If so, it should use a replication rule (which I have already predefined) to replicate these objects to my Bucket 2. This way, tagged objects will be replicated from Bucket 1 to Bucket 2. To achieve this, I have utilized the resources provided by IBM in their documentation (https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-replication-overview#versioning-sdks-node). My code looks like this... However, when I test my action, it seems to 'work,' but no objects are replicated. Therefore, I need your assistance to determine if the issue is with my code or elsewhere.

```
function main(params) {
    const IBM = require('ibm-cos-sdk');

    var config = {
        endpoint: 'https://s3.eu-de.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/blabla', //blabla = nom du cos
        apiKeyId: '...', // id d'une clé API que j'ai crée moi-même
        serviceInstanceId: 'ServiceId-....', //Correspondant a mon cos
    };

    var cos = new IBM.S3(config);

    var putBucketReplicationParams = {
        Bucket: 'bucket1', /* bucket source*/
        ReplicationConfiguration: {
            Role: 'crn:v1:bluemix:public:iam::4:<id_account>:role:Administrator', /*4e04b1af38b448ba93699daeb292d445 correspond au id account*/
            Rules: [ 
                {
                    Destination: {
                        Bucket: 'bucket2', /* bucket de destination */
                    },
                    Status: 'Enabled',
                    DeleteMarkerReplication: { /* fait correspondre le contenu du cos source et destination */
                        Status: 'Enabled',
                    },
                    Filter: {
                        And: {
                            Tags: [ /* tag qui va permettre d'identifier les objets à répliquer vers les USA */
                                {
                                    Key: 'key',
                                    Value: 'replication',
                                }
                                // Ajoutez d'autres éléments ici si nécessaire
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    
                    ID: 'Replication', /* ID de la règle de réplication */
                    Priority: '0'
                }
            ]
        }
    };

    // Ajout de journalisation pour indiquer le début de l'opération
    console.log('Début de l\'opération de réplication.');

    cos.putBucketReplication(putBucketReplicationParams, function(err, data) { // Vérifie si la fonction a fonctionné ou pas
        if (err) {
            console.error('Erreur lors de la réplication :', err);
            // Ajout de journalisation pour les erreurs
            return { error: err.message };
        } else {
            console.log('Réplication réussie :', data);
            // Ajout de journalisation pour les réussites
            return data;
        }
    });
    
    // Ajout de journalisation pour indiquer la fin de l'opération
    console.log('Fin de l\'opération de réplication.');
}
```

Actually the result is:

> Activation ID:
> 8....
> Results:
> {}
> Logs:
> [
> "   stdout: Début de l'opération de réplication.",
> "   stdout: Fin de l'opération de réplication."
> ]

But no data was replicated

Comment: The last parameter to cos.putBucketReplication was a function(err, data){} that should have logged something when it completed.  Yet nothing was logged?

Comment: @PowellQuiring, non rien du tout ne met renvoyer